# Django Rest Framework Serializers validate passes for one but fails on another

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

Here's what I currently have:

models.py:

```
class Team(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.label


class AppName(models.Model):
    label = models.CharField(max_length=128, unique=True)

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return self.label
```

serializers.py

```
class TeamSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Team
        fields = [
            'id',
            'label'
        ]
class AppNameSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = AppName
        fields = [
            'id',
            'label'
        ]
```

This is my function:

```
    appname = AppNameSerializer(data={'label': request.POST.get('appname')})
    if appname.is_valid():
        appname = appname.save()

    team = TeamSerializer(data={'label': request.POST.get('team')})
    if team.is_valid():
        team = team.save()
```

where request.POST.get('appname') is 'foo-name' and request.POST.get('team') is 'Chocobo Knights'

Why is appname.is_valid() throwing invalid? whereas team.is_valid() passes? They're effectively the same code, I'm so confused.

```
TeamSerializer(data={'label': 'Chocobo Knights'}):
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    label = CharField(max_length=128, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=Team.objects.all())>]) True
AppNameSerializer(data={'label': 'foo-app'}):
    id = IntegerField(label='ID', read_only=True)
    label = CharField(max_length=128, validators=[<UniqueValidator(queryset=AppName.objects.all())>]) False
```

Is this the right approach given the DB uniquevalidator?

```
    appname = AppNameSerializer(data={'label': request.POST.get('appname')})
    if appname.is_valid():
        appname = appname.save()
    else:
        appname = AppName.objects.get(**appname.data)

    team = TeamSerializer(data={'label': request.POST.get('team')})
    if team.is_valid():
        team = team.save()
    else:
        team = Team.objects.get(**team.data)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your serializers validation depends on the state of the database.

The code might be the same, but if the Team table already has a "Chocobo Knights" while AppName does not have any "foo-app"... don't expect the same results for both!

Comment: Wait, so does is_valid() check for the existence in DB? If it already exists it bails?